Creating a VBA Excel macro that creates an Outlook meeting invitation using text and formatting from a Word document. (Office 365)
The macro mostly works, but it has weird behavior: I need to have the Word document open, or else I get errors. Also, it takes a while to execute and tries opening the doc again in read-only. I'm definitely not using best practices here (next on my list is to use named ranges instead of Column A). I would like some suggestions for making it run better so I can pass it on to others.
The code:
Sub TeamsMeetingInvitation()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMeet As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim BodyContent As String
   
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("Scheduler")
   
    'Loop invitation creator
   
    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If sht.Range("G" & i).Value = "Invite" Then
       
            Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
            Set OutMeet = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
            Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\to\document\z.docx", ReadOnly = True)
            WordDoc.Content.Copy
            BodyContent = WordDoc.Content.Text
            'Create this invitation
           
            With OutMeet
            .Start = sht.Range("E" & i).Value 
            .Duration = 30
            .Subject = sht.Range("N" & i).Value
            .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
            .RequiredAttendees = sht.Range("M" & i).Value
            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            .GetInspector.WordEditor.Content.Paste
            .Display
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            End With
           
            With OutMeet.GetInspector.WordEditor.Content.Find
            .Text = "zzzzzz"
            .Replacement.Text = sht.Range("L" & i).Value 'Enter relevant date and time
            .Execute Replace:=2 ' 2 = wdReplaceAll
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
            End With
           
        End If
    Next i
    ' Clean up
    WordDoc.Close False
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set OutMeet = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
     
End Sub

I made the above code and tried some basic cleanup. I tried using AI to help, and it got me a bit further, but I'm still not happy with the result.
The error: z.docx is locked for editing by 'another user'. I click to open a read-only copy, and then it works just fine.

ReadOnly = True should be ReadOnly := True

You could consider creating your OutMeet from a saved template which already has the needed content, instead of copy/pasting from Word.

The error is probably because you are creating a new instance of the word application and trying to open the same document in it, for every iteration in the loop. Best to move CreateObject and even the assignment to OutApp outside the loop.

I think only minor changes are necessary:
Sub TeamsMeetingInvitation()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMeet As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim BodyContent As String

    'Get Content out of Word
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Path\to\document\z.docx", ReadOnly = True)
    WordDoc.Content.Copy
    BodyContent = WordDoc.Content.Text
    WordDoc.Close False
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
   
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("Scheduler")
   
    'Loop invitation creator
   
    For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If sht.Range("G" & i).Value = "Invite" Then
       
            Set OutApp = Outlook.Application
            Set OutMeet = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
            'Create this invitation
           
            With OutMeet
            .Start = sht.Range("E" & i).Value 
            .Duration = 30
            .Subject = sht.Range("N" & i).Value
            .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
            .Body = Replace(BodyContent, "zzzzzz", sht.Range("L" & i).Value)
            .RequiredAttendees = sht.Range("M" & i).Value
            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            .GetInspector.WordEditor.Content.Paste
            .Display
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
            End With
           
        End If
    Next i
    ' Clean up
    Set OutMeet = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
     
End Sub

